# Open Row insert- SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulk-insert, openrowset, oledb

When we run a SSIS package to import data from excel , we get an initial error:

```
The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered.
If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode.
```

We were able to fix this by executing the package in 32 bit mode
using the option in wizard

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp13
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',   
                    'Data Source=XXXXXXXX;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Sheet1$];
```

We get the below error

```
The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 
cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7438).
The step failed.
```

Is there any option to run the Transaction SQL in 32 bit .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103055/2497152

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

1. Download the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for Windows, 64 bit version found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
2. Install it on your server.
3. Check the user running SQL Server and make sure that user has access to the temp directory `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp` if it's a local service account or `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp` if it's a network service account.
4. Configure '**Ad Hoc Distributed Queries**' and enable the **`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB`** files like this:

Here's the SP_CONFIGURE/RECONFIGURE commands:

```
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1; 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 

EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1; 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 

EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1   
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParam', 1
```

Based on your SQL Server version, you might need to use `DynamicParameters` instead of `DynamicParam`

FYI, On SQL Server 2014, we have used `EXEC sp_configure` and use `DynamicParameters` instead of `DynamicParam`

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
```

Make sure you register msexcl40.dll:

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msexcl40.dll
```

Edited:

You might have to check the excel versions like xlsx or xls. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , After installing the driver , XLSX files worked but not XLS . We are using data from mutliple source so few files are in XLS .

Comment: @LakshmiR did you choose the excel version for XLSX or XLS?